# Incrementing a number 5 times in MASM

Tags: assembly, masm, dosbox

In the following assembly language program to increment a number 5 times, after incrementing the number, the message should be displayed only once, but in my case, it is displayed twice. The situation does not arise if instead of using NUM as a named memory location, I use only BL as register to store input value and perform computations on it. Why so?

```
DATA_HERE SEGMENT
  MSG DB "ENTER THE NUMBER:   $"
  MSG1 DB "NUMBER AFTER INCREMENTING 5 TIMES:   $"
  NUM DB ?
DATA_HERE ENDS

CODE_HERE SEGMENT
ASSUME CS:CODE_HERE, DS:DATA_HERE
START:
  MOV AX, DATA_HERE
  MOV DS, AX

  LEA DX, MSG
  MOV AH, 09H
  INT 21H

  MOV AH, 01H
  INT 21H
  MOV NUM, AL

  ;NEWLINE
  MOV AH, 02H
  MOV DL, 0DH
  INT 21H
  MOV DL, 0AH
  INT 21H

  MOV CL, 05H
REPEAT:
  INC NUM
  DEC CL
  JNZ REPEAT

  LEA DX, MSG1
  MOV AH, 09H
  INT 21H

  MOV DL, NUM
  MOV AH, 02H
  INT 21H    
CODE_HERE ENDS
END START
```

Output is:

```
ENTER THE NUMBER:    2
NUMBER AFTER INCREMENTING 5 TIMES:    7
NUMBER AFTER INCREMENTING 5 TIMES:    _
```

Also, I am assuming that my number after incrementing will be less than 9.

What to do if

1. I want to take an n-digit input (DOSBox will just take one digit as input and move onto next instruction)
2. I want to display an n-digit output

Comment: Shouldn't you be doing something to finish the program, such as INT21 with AH=4C at the end of the code?

Comment: @CecilioPardo Thanks for the comment :). Yes adding the finish statement did remove the error. But I am unable to understand why this didn't occur when I used BL to store input. Also, can you throw some light on the latter two doubts.

Comment: If you don't exit the program properly, the processor will go on and execute whatever it finds after your code, which is garbage. So the results are unpredictable.

Comment: re: multi-digit input/output: see the FAQ section in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info

Comment: `inc` 5 times is pointless; use `add num, 5`, or better keep it in a register.